# Can Airplane security devices damage games consoles?

Tags: airport-security

Okay so I’m leaving tomorrow morning and I wanted to take my ps4 but I’ve been told that the scanners can damage your console and wipe everything on it. Is it safe to bring it?

Comment: Most definitely not the case!

Comment: Who told you that? Can you reference a source? This is utter nonsense.

Comment: Remember that a modern games console uses basically the same components as a laptop computer, and many, many people fly with these without issue.

Answer (score 11):

People put phones, cameras, laptops, hard drives, USB sticks, and all manner of other electronic devices through the airport security scanners every day, all without any damage or loss of information.

Your PS4 will be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 3):

Are you going to put it in a suitcase and check it? Then yes, it can get damaged by the baggage handling process. Bags get dropped, stacked, flipped and stuffed. It could hurt one of the components of your system. So don’t put it in your checked luggage — or if you must check it as luggage, put it in the original box with the original styrofoam packing, and then double box it in a larger box with more foam packing.

If you’re carrying it on board as cabin hand luggage then there’s really no problem. Just don’t drop it.

Answer (score 1):

While I have never brought a game console through security I have carried laptops through security for the last 20 years, never have they been damaged.

The only thing there with even the slightest damage potential is the walk through metal detector, your gear doesn't go through it and even then the only thing that would even remotely concern me would be floppy disks.  You know those things where somebody 3D printed a save icon :)  Certainly not something that sees much use these days.

Answer (score 0):

I brought a classic Wii through full security. I got yelled at for not taking it out of the bag, but no issues with the unit or TSA.

The TSA really doesn't use magnetic scanners. X-Rays and millimeter scanners won't harm electronics (or nobody would bring them on trips)